# How to create array using predicates?

Tags: swift, macos, core-data, nspredicate

I have an NSCollectionView, and a sidebar with folders. Each folder is an object in core data that has a relationship to all of it's individual files. When a folder is selected, I would like to create an array of the files (that pertain to the specific folder) and have them displayed in the NSCollectionView. I have been researching core data for a few days now and I think using a predicate would be the best option for this, but I'm not entirely sure as I've never actually used predicates before. (I'm still using Swift 3.0)

JuggleItems -> Folders. JFiles -> Files inside of folder.

[JuggleItems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2StD.png)
[JFiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7woJt.png)

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-relationships-and-more-fetching--cms-25070 This is where I've been getting all of my information, but unfortunately it hasn't been updated for Swift 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have created a one-to-many relationship between a `Folder` object and the files it contains it seems like you shouldn't have to perform a separate fetch for the files as you should be able to access them simply by saying `folder.files` (or whatever you named the `NSSet` created by the relationship.)  Of course `folder.files` would be a `NSSet`, and not an `Array`, but you can say `folder.files.allObjects` to get them in `Array` form.

If you can show what your Core Data folder and file objects look like we will be able to give more exact advice.

Comment: I updated it with pictures, let me know if you would like to see anything else.

Comment: OK, well then I got it almost exactly right.  `juggleItem.jFiles.allObjects` gets you an `Array` of your files.

Comment: So the "juggleItem" in juggleItem.jFiles.allObjects is the name of the entity, but technically all of the "JuggleItem"s (Folders) are auto-named the same thing, and can only be differentiated by their attribute : name. Could I do something like    (juggleItem with identifier name: Personal).jFiles.allObjects?

Comment: Try it.  I don't really understand why that's necessary, though, as you said you can select the folder in your collectionView.  So in your collectionView delegate method `didSelectItem atIndexPath` you should be able to get a reference to the specific folder, right?